# UITextView text is aligned to the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am creating a `UIScrollView` and setting the **attributedText**. For some reason the text was not appearing...until I actually scrolled down. It seems the text is being aligned to the **bottom** of the `UIScrollView`, and I have no idea why?!

```
NSString *description = NSLocalizedString(@"forgot.description", nil);
NSMutableAttributedString *paragraph = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:description attributes:@{}];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:4];
[paragraph addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [paragraph length])];
[paragraph addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, [paragraph length])];
[paragraph addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:43/255.0f green:47/255.0f blue:61/255.0f alpha:1.0f] range:NSMakeRange(0, [paragraph length])];
_descriptionTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
_descriptionTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_descriptionTextView.attributedText = paragraph;
_descriptionTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_descriptionTextView.scrollEnabled = NO;
_descriptionTextView.clipsToBounds = NO;

CGFloat const ComponentWidth = 280.0;
CGFloat const ComponentHeight = 40.0;
self.descriptionTextView.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(x, y, ComponentWidth, ComponentHeight));
[self.view addSubview:self.descriptionTextView];
```

[image]

I think this has to do with the navigationBar when I set it to not hidden

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: in your code i am not able to see addsubview method

Comment: In the question, do you mean `UITextView` (which scrolls) when you write `UIScrollView`? Because that's what you are adding all the stuff to...

Comment: Could you give a link to the sample project? I tested this code, and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: [scrollview addSubview: _descriptionTextView]

Comment: sorry - Yes I meant UITextView

Comment: What is the x and y in CGRectMake(x, y, ComponentWidth, ComponentHeight)?